# How to exclude certain packages from API documentation using Dokka

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

i have two packages  "../java/abc"(.java) and "../java/xyz"(.kt)  
i need to exclude abc package content in dokka html document

basically i could see both the package are documented in HTML by dokka. after performing  
'./gradlew dokkaHtml'

can anybody give me a solution where i can customize/limit the documentation only for 1 package?

i have plugin and dependency in project level build.gradel file

```
dependencies {
classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
}

plugins {
id 'org.jetbrains.dokka' version '1.6.21' apply false
}
```

my app.gredel file look like below

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'

tasks.dokkaHtml.configure {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach {
            perPackageOption {
                matchingRegex.set("abc")
                suppress.set(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have also tried the below syntax

```
tasks.dokkaHtml.configure {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach {
            perPackageOption {
                prefix = "abc"
                suppress = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Expectation: need to customize the documentation for only 1 package.